# Biblatex 2.7 and \DefineBibliographyStrings

Tags: biblatex, babel, polyglossia

I downloaded the latest version 2.7. If I use

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{%
    namedash={---------},%
    volumeof={de},%
    url={Disponível em: },%
    shorthands={Abreviaturas}
}
```

namedash and volumeof work, but url and shorthands don't (either using babel or polyglossia).

Version 2.5 works without problems (I don't even need to specify "shorthands").

Is there anything I can do to make it work with 2.7?

Comment: `brazil.lbx` didn't work in 2.6 due to a typo in `brazilian.lbx`. This has been fixed in 2.7, but the [dev version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/) has been updated a few times. I get no issues with this code under the latest update (2013/06/23), provided that new strings are initialized with: \NewBibliographyString{namedash,volumeof}

Comment: I didn't know \NewBibliographyString{namedash,volumeof}  was needed -- thought it was provided by the "historian" style. Anyway,as I said, namedash and volumeof work, but _url_ and _shorthands_ don't (I also used the latest update.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all versions but 2.5, `biblatex.def` uses the default `url` field format:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

To use the format from 2.5, drop the punctuation in your `url` string definition and add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

In `historian.cbx` the style imposes unabbreviated strings with:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{abbreviate=false,dateabbrev=false}
```

You can revert back to abbreviated strings by loading biblatex with `abbreviate=true`. Or define `shorthands` with the abbreviated string by default, as you've done via `\DefineBibliographyStrings`

Comment: Worked fine, though I still had to modify: \renewcommand*{\losname} for abbreviations.

Comment: @Joseph I don't see why that is necessary, if you enable `abbreviate` after `style=historian`. In any case it is difficult to sort out all the issues here without a MWE.